# Stove causing GFCI outlet to trip

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I installed a GFCI outlet with the source being from another outlet (non-GFCI). from this GFCI outlet there is another outlet downstream but it is wired from the LINE of the other GFCI instead of the LOAD. When i plug the stove into the GFCI outlet, the outlet downstream trips. I have tried different brands of outlets but it keeps happening. So i changed the outlet that the stove connects to a (non-GFCI outlet) but once I plug in the stove, the GFCI outlet still trips. I have tried different GFCI outlets but it still trips, and its not like other cases where the electronic ignition of the stove causes the outlet to trip because as soon as it is plugged in it trips. The outlet still trips even if it is the only thing connected to the outlet and even if there is something else connected to the outlet. What could be causing this?

Comment: Wild idea -- try plugging your stove into an EMI-filtering surge suppressor or dedicated EMI filter.  Arcs and sparks produce broadband electrical noise -- this might be getting coupled down the power lines into the GFCIs and confusing them into tripping.

Comment: The simplest explanation is the most likely. **The stove has a ground fault**.

Comment: I was think of electric stove on my original (deleted comment) if the stove is tripping the GFCI when trying to light I like ThreePhaseEel'S suggestion. Some states exempt stoves from GFCI rrequirements.